# Set StorageController in Parse-SDK-JS

Tags: parse-platform, parse-javascript-sdk

i am developing an ionic app so i want to use the ionic storage module to store data on the device.

Parse is the backend so i have to tell the parse SDK that it should use the Ionic Storage. I build a StorageController like the included react-native one the use the ionic storage, but can't find a way to set the StorageController without cloning the SDK, alter Storage.js and add another else clause

```
if (process.env.PARSE_BUILD === 'react-native') {
  CoreManager.setStorageController(require('./StorageController.react-native'));
} else if (process.env.PARSE_BUILD === 'ionic') {
  CoreManager.setStorageController(require('./StorageController.ionic'));
} else if (process.env.PARSE_BUILD === 'browser') {
  CoreManager.setStorageController(require('./StorageController.browser'));
} else {
  CoreManager.setStorageController(require('./StorageController.default'));
}
```

is there a way to call `CoreManager.setStorageController` on the fly while parse initialisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to do this:

```
const Parse = require('parse');
const ionicController = require('./StorageController.ionic');

Parse.CoreManager.setStorageController(ionicController);
```

Comment: I have to cast Parse to any because it's TypeScript and CoreManager is not in the definition file but it works this way!